# How to write to geopandas dataframe directly to (Google) Cloud Storage?

Tags: python, geopandas, fiona

I would like to write a geopandas.Dataframe directly to (Google) cloud storage, from the documentation fiona enables this, however I am not sure how to supply the correct `**kwargs` for the geopandas.Dataframe.to_file function. any examples?

```
import geopandas
gdf = geopandas.read_file("my-file.shp")
gdf.to_file("gs://my-bucket/my-file.shp", driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Answer (score 1):

GeoPandas relies on Fiona/GDAL which has trouble writing to cloud storage.
Try this instead:
If you have a service account that can access the bucket with Storage Admin (or at least Storage Create and Storage Read)
Create a key for the service account and store it locally.
Set the environment variable:

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/key_file.json"`

Then the following should work.

```
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
from gcsfs import GCSFileSystem
import geopandas

with MemoryFile() as mem_dst:
    gdf = geopandas.read_file("my-file.shp")
    gdf.to_file(mem_dst.name, driver='ESRI Shapefile')
    #"UPLOAD TO CLOUD"
    fs=GCSFileSystem()
    with fs.open("gs://mybucketname/objectname.shp", 'wb') as file:
        result = file.write(mem_dst.read())
```

You could use a local disk file instead of a memory file.